# How do I duplicate UIViews from IB programmatically?

Tags: ios

I need to add a UIView created in IB multiple times to a scrollView. Kind of like a TableView Cell.  The code below only creates the View once. I could of course create the UIView programmatically and make it work, however that makes AutoLayout more difficult.

**Question:**  How can I create a View with subview (eg ImageView, Labels etc) in StoryBoard and duplicate it in a scrollView?

```
class ScrollViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView!

let scrollView = UIScrollView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let height = CGFloat(200.0)

    self.scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds

    //Make scrollView (height) = number of UIViews
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, height*2) 
    self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)

    var y = CGFloat(0.0)

    for i in 0..<2 {

        backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, 20, 20)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(backgroundView)

    y += height
    }

}
```

[image: see screenshot:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to put the view in its own XIB. In code, create a single instance of [`UINib`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINib_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UINib/nibWithNibName:bundle:) and send it [`instantiateWithOwner:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINib_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINib/instantiateWithOwner:options:) repeatedly. This is probably the simplest solution.

If you insist on using a storyboard, you can put the view under its own view controller. Then you can load multiple copies of both the view controller and the view using [`-[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:). To do this properly, you'll need to learn about [view controller containment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).

Another approach is to serialize the view to an archive using [`+[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedArchiver/archivedDataWithRootObject:). Then you can deserialize the archiver repeatedly with [`+[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedUnarchiver/unarchiveObjectWithData:). However, if your view (or any of its descendant views) has a reference to some other object (like a model or controller object), you may end up duplicating a much larger object graph than you intended.

#### UPDATE

Let's say you created a custom subclass of `UIView` named `MyView`. Create a XIB by choosing File > New > File from the menu bar. In the dialog box, choose iOS > User Interface, then click the View icon.  Name the XIB `MyView.xib`.  Set the custom class of the view in the XIB to `MyView`. Lay out the subviews of `MyView`, set up constraints, and hook up the outlets of `MyView` to its subviews.

To load the XIB, you'll want to create an instance of `UINib` and then send it `instantiateWithOwner:options:` repeatedly. I would do it in a class method on `MyView`, like this:

```
@implementation MyView

static UINib *nib;

+ (instancetype)instantiate {
    if (nib == 0) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveMemoryWarning) name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:nil];
        NSString *myClassName = NSStringFromClass(self);
        NSBundle *myClassBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:self];
        nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:myClassName bundle:myClassBundle];
    }

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil];
    return [topLevelObjects firstObject];
}

+ (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:nil];
    nib = nil;
}

@end
```

Note that I've gone to some extra trouble here to discard the `UINib` object on a low-memory warning.

Anyway, to create an instance of `MyView`, you can just do this:

```
MyView *myView = [MyView instantiate];
```

That will create the `UINib` object if necessary, and then ask it to instantiate the view.  Each call will return a new instance of `MyView` loaded from the XIB.

Comment: Would it be a easier to learn how to do AutoLayout programatically and create a New UIView for each loop?  Or is it a good idea to just create One UIView and reuse it ?

Comment: I would just put the view in its own XIB.

Comment: I am not sure what that means or entails.  The whole idea is that I want to create the View in storyboard so that I can do autolayout there.  Will your solution allow me to do this?

Comment: You can use auto layout in XIBs.

Comment: Ok, I now have figured out what XIB stand for....!  Thank you.  Would it be possible if you could please explain:  In code, create a single instance of UINib and send it instantiateWithOwner:options: repeatedly. ?

Comment: Thank you Rob.  It is Objective-C code, not swift but I will try to translate it and see if I can get it to work.  I might get back to you.  Thank you so much for your help so far. Have a nice weekend !

Comment: Ok so, I managed to create a View in XIB and I am able to load it in the Viewcontroller, however the Autolayout does not carry over from the constraints in the xib.  How can I use your suggestion and have the custom view's (I need multiples of them) to resize/work with autolayout? ( I realise that if I only needed 1 view I can add a view in Storyboard and set custom class to CustomView and set constraints, however, I need multiples..)  Any idea?

Comment: Hi Rob, I have spent four days researching and implementing your suggestion, I have a follow up question about auto-layout and posted a new question.  Could you please be so kind and have a look - any help would be really appreciated !  Regards, Karl   

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569752/how-do-i-duplicate-uiview-added-to-viewcontroller-in-storyboard-and-keep-constra