# How do I duplicate UIView added to ViewController in StoryBoard and keep constraints?

Tags: ios

I have created a view, CustomView.xib, and a dedicated class, CustomView.swift.  I have added it to my ViewController in Storyboard by adding a view and setting the custom class to CustomView.swift and it works perfectly. The constraints I added in StoryBoard resize the nib like I want.  Now I want to create copies of it, like cells/rows in a tableView (like a twitterfeed).  How can I do that, while maintaining the constraints so that it resize correctly?  I guess my question boils down to: How do you duplicate UIViews created in StoryBoard? I realise that the top constraint might have to be altered as row's are added. And second, since this is a nib, how can I change the label within it?  The project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/karlml/CustomViewNib.git)

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

```
import UIKit

class ScrollViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let height = CGFloat(200.0)

        self.scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, height*3)
        self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)


        var y = CGFloat(0.0)

        for i in 0..<2 {

            //DO I ADD IBOUTLET(s)?
            // How do I set width of frame to the View in StoryBoard (that has constraints?
            //Do I tag it, give it an ID - How can I create copies of the customView from StoryBoard

            let customView = CustomView(frame: CGRectMake(0, y, 320, 200))
            self.scrollView.addSubview(customView)

            y += height
        }

    }



    func createCustomView(index: Int) -> UIView {
        //How do I instantiate the view here without setting the frame size?
        let customView = CustomView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200))

        if index == 0{
            customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            //How do I change the label text, like below?
            //customView.label.text = "New York"
        }

        if index == 1{
            customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            //How do I change the label text, like below?
            //customView.label.text = "Tokyo"

        }

        return customView
    }


}
```